# Error occured processing XML 'Unable to load schema mappings from location

Tags: java, spring, maven

I fetched an existing maven from my repo then when I open with eclipse I get this error:

```
Error occured processing XML 'Unable to load schema mappings from location [META-INF/spring.schemas]'. 
See Error Log for more details  security-context.xml    /myapp/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet    Unknown Spring Beans Problem
```

Do I need to put spring.schemas into META-INF folder manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to clean your jars, maybe one of them is corrupted.

Right click on your projects -> Run As -> Maven clean. 
Then:
Right click on your projects -> Run As -> Maven build.

You can do it from the command line with "mvn clean" and "mvn build"

Comment: There is no maven goal called 'build'. Use 'compile' or 'install'. You  should also chain maven commands together, e.g. mvn clean install -DskipTests

Answer (score 0):

Kindly check your pom.xml file, it way miss match the version of

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```