# Unknown Spring Error showing up in Spring Tool Suite (and in all Spring Projects) How do I resolve this?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-tool-suite

I am getting a pair of errors (duplicate errors) that state the following

> Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type
>   Error occured processing XML 'Unable to load schema mappings from location [META-INF/spring.schemas]'. See Error Log for more details   root-context.xml    /StudentInformationSystem/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring    Unknown Spring Beans Problem

I had a fresh install of Eclipse with Spring Tool Suite, and a fresh install of Spring Tool Suite 3.4.0 Release.  I'm using the Windows 32 bit version, and I've developing using the latest Java SDK (1.7.0_51)  I'm on 64 bit Windows 7.

These two errors occur in the /src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml and /StudentInformationSystem/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml

When I try to run Spring MVC projects with this error, I see a Java OutOfBounds error as it mounts to the tc-server (the server that comes packages with Spring Tool Suite)

> Could not publish to the server. java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException

This has been a very perplexing error as I can't seem to find an issue with my spring installation, my server installation, or anything wrong with running other types of projects (spring projects/appications from the console)

I'm assuming this is related to MVC specifically, but the many Spring MVC template projects not working questions and their solutions have not helped me through the issue (although I may need to keep digging, there seem to be a lot of them with different wordings)

Any help with this would be appreciated.  The same error occurs when I use imports of projects that I know work in the environments on my peers computers (I have an entire group that are running the same application that don't have the issue)

Comment: Show the contents of the files that are throwing errors. We're not psychics and cannot know what you've written there. Also add a longer stack trace to the `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: Have you tried doing a Clean/Build on all of the projects?

Comment: Have you been to this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11833928/error-occured-processing-xml-unable-to-load-schema-mappings-from-location

Comment: The two files have nothing added, they were based on templates.  There was no stack trace produced for the IndexOutOfBoundsException.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking through several similar issues mentioned on Stack Overflow, the safest bet seems that my Maven jar files are corrupted.  I discovered that fresh installs of my system were not replacing the .m2/repositories folder.  I deleted it, and while building and cleaning the maven project from Spring Tool Suite and Eclipse, the repository was automatically downloaded, and the errors went away.

In terms of cleaning things up, I have realized this question may be considered a duplicate.

This is the closest question/solution I found on stack overflow: [some error while running spring mvc project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10292103/some-error-while-running-spring-mvc-project?rq=1)